# Bulk insert not retaining special chars of txt file SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encoding

I have a stored procedure that bulk imports a text file and inserts it into my database.

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.TEMP_STORE
(
    ID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [MONTH] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [YEAR] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    STORE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    SUBMITTAL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ENTITY NVARCHAR(MAX),
    SUBMITTAL_TYPE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    iCOUNT NVARCHAR(MAX),
    STATE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    COUNTRY NVARCHAR(MAX),
    REGION NVARCHAR(MAX),
    GLOBAL_REGION NVARCHAR(MAX),
    LOCAL_CURRENCY NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

--SELECT * FROM DBO.TEMP_STORE
--prepare bulk insert query to load data from file to temp table
SET @SQL='BULK INSERT DBO.TEMP_STORE FROM '''+ @FilePath+''''
SET @SQL=@SQL+'WITH ('
SET @SQL=@SQL+'DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',' 
SET @SQL=@SQL+'FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'','
--SET @SQL=@SQL+'ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'','
SET @SQL=@SQL+'ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + nchar(10) + ''','
SET @SQL=@SQL+'FIRSTROW =2)'

--print @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

For instance, importing Update ROLLING_CONE_SHOP_DETAIL set SHOP_STATE = 'São Paulo' results in storing the data as'S+úo Paulo' when I select the same row that was imported.  I can update the row and explicitly fix the fix the issue:

```
UPDATE TEMP_STORE 
SET STATE = 'São Paulo' 
WHERE STATE= 'S+úo Paulo'
```

But when I do my Bulk insert, it does not retain the special character. I have confirmed the text file I am importing is saved at utf-8 and contains the correct character.

How can I make sure my bulk inset retains the special character properly?

EDIT: This question differs from the "duplicate" question in that I am not looking to import data as UTF-8, I am looking to import data that retains my special characters.

Perhaps removing utf-8 from title would avoid the confusion

Comment: SQL Server 2008 doesn't support UTF-8, I'm afraid. The first version that will is SQL Server 2019. You won't be able to use `BULK INSERT` to import a UTF-8 file reliably.

Comment: You can use a powershell command like `gc data.txt | out-file data2.txt -Encoding Unicode` to re-endode the file.

Comment: @Larnu how come I can store the information correctly via an update but not a bulk insert?

Comment: Because you're not using UTF-8 when you write that SQL Statement.

Comment: @Larnu if I can bulk inset in the same encoding as the SQL statement, shouldn't it work regardless of the file encoding?

Comment: `UPDATE` isn't a `BULK INSERT`. They are 2 completely different things. `BULK INSERT` is reading the file from disc, which is in UTF-8 (and hence why the character is lost). When you write the `UPDATE` statement the **literal** string is interpreted in the collation that your database/column is using, and so the character isn't "lost".

Comment: @Larnu I figured it out, all that needed to be done was to change the encoding of the file from utf-8 to ANSI.  The characters persisted through the Bulk Insert

Comment: Yes, that's why @DavidBrowne-Microsoft suggested using powershell to change the encode..